# serilog-sinks-mssqlserver: Exclude column in xml Config file

Tags: c#, serilog

How to exclude column in xml config file ?

I want to do this serilogColumnOptions.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties); event in config file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like it's not possible to remove Serilog columns through XML configuration.

I have found several confirmations of this statement: [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/issues/74#issuecomment-284556619) and [here](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/04/xml-configuration-for-serilog/#comment-2521303319).

You could also verify this by examining [source code](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/LoggerConfigurationMSSqlServerExtensions.cs) for SQL Server Sink:

`MSSqlServer()` extension method checks for `MSSqlServerSettingsSection` section for configuring columns like described in [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#xml-configuration-for-columns).

```
MSSqlServerConfigurationSection serviceConfigSection =
    ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MSSqlServerSettingsSection") as MSSqlServerConfigurationSection;

// If we have additional columns from config, load them as well
if (serviceConfigSection != null && serviceConfigSection.Columns.Count > 0)
{
    if (columnOptions == null)
    {
        columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
    }
    GenerateDataColumnsFromConfig(serviceConfigSection, columnOptions);
}
```

If you then examine `GenerateDataColumnsFromConfig()` method you'll see that all configured columns are just added to `AdditionalDataColumns` collection of `ColumnOptions`.
But there is no any code for removing columns from `Store` collection.

If it's a must for your application to have file configuration for Serilog and have possibility to remove some columns, you could add simple replacement for Serilog configuration from file. Here is a sample implementation for such configuration:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString"];
var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName"];
var autoCreateSqlTable = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.autoCreateSqlTable"]);
var excludedColumns = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.excludedColumns"];

ColumnOptions columnOptions = new ColumnOptions();
foreach (var excludedColumn in Regex.Split(excludedColumns, ",\\s*"))
{
    columnOptions.Store.Remove((StandardColumn)Enum.Parse(typeof(StandardColumn), excludedColumn, true));
}

Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(connectionString, tableName, columnOptions: columnOptions, autoCreateSqlTable: autoCreateSqlTable)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Here is `appSettings` section:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:using:MSSqlSever" value="Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" />
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.connectionString" value="Server=.;Database=LoggingDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.tableName" value="Logs"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.autoCreateSqlTable" value="true"/>
    <add key="serilog:write-to:MSSqlServer.excludedColumns" value="Properties, TimeStamp"/>
  </appSettings>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This line of code saved me `columnOptions.Store.Remove((StandardColumn)Enum.Parse(typeof(StandardColumn), excludedColumn, true));` ... thank you